# PyEphem: What is the epoch attribute for EarthSatellite

Tags: pyephem, satellite

I am using PyEphem to predict satellite passage over a point in a constellation design project.

I would answer my question by it is orbit epoch but I would like to be sure. Here is an example that rose the question at first:

### What works

Here is the result I get with PyEphem (With only one date per access), compared with STK (see below to see how I obtained it):

```
2014/4/27 03:37:59
2014/4/28 03:15:59
2014/4/29 02:53:59
2014/4/30 02:31:59
2014/5/1 02:09:59
2014/5/2 01:47:59
2014/5/5 00:42:09
2014/5/6 00:20:09
2014/5/6 23:58:09
2014/5/7 23:36:19
2014/5/8 23:14:19
2014/5/9 22:52:19
2014/5/10 22:30:19

27 Apr 2014 03:43:08.427
28 Apr 2014 03:20:44.792
29 Apr 2014 02:58:21.163
30 Apr 2014 02:35:57.546
1 May 2014 02:13:33.952
2 May 2014 01:51:10.384
3 May 2014 01:28:46.848
4 May 2014 01:06:23.358
5 May 2014 00:43:59.92
6 May 2014 00:21:36.571
6 May 2014 23:59:13.310
7 May 2014 23:36:50.173
8 May 2014 23:14:27.216
9 May 2014 22:52:04.550
10 May 2014 22:29:42.571
```

Set up in for PyEphem

```
import numpy as np
import ephem, math


sat = ephem.EarthSatellite()
sat._e = 1.4538821258014423e-09
sat._M = 136.92
sat._ap = 0.0
sat._raan = 199.662
sma = 6878.13631
sat._n = 86400  * np.sqrt(398600.4418/sma**3) / (2*np.pi)
sat._epoch = '2014/02/14 13:00:00'
sat._inc = 46.8
satellite = sat
target = ephem.Observer()
target.lon, target.lat = '6.9', '46.8'
tr = ephem.Date('2014/04/26 16:00:00')
tend = ephem.Date('2014/05/13 16:00:00')
satellite.compute(target)
ephemeris = []

while tr < tend:
    target.date = tr
    satellite.compute(target)
    alt = satellite.alt
    h = satellite.range / 1000
    tr = ephem.Date(tr +  10.0*ephem.second)
    if alt <=0: 
        tr = ephem.Date(tr + 60.0 * 10 * ephem.second)
        continue
    Ona = np.arctan(6378 * np.cos(alt)/(h + 6378 * np.sin(alt))) # Target ONA

    alt = np.degrees(alt)
    if np.fabs(math.degrees(Ona)) > 5 :continue
        ephemeris.append(tr)
print ephemeris
```

Here is the STK setup (the dates for the experiment are the same):[STK satellite setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beQZj.png)

So that is almost perfect, even if I don't understand why there is this one hour difference between STK and PyEphem epoch, I suspect something with the UTCG thing.

### What does not

Now, If I increase the inclination to 49, I get these results (PyEphem first, Stk then):

```
2014/5/12 00:01:19
2014/5/12 23:39:29

5 May 2014 02:45:25.831
6 May 2014 02:23:14.987
7 May 2014 02:01:06.514
8 May 2014 01:38:58.566
9 May 2014 01:16:50.962
10 May 2014 00:54:43.643
11 May 2014 00:32:36.592
12 May 2014 00:10:29.850
12 May 2014 23:48:23.509
```

By setting the epoch to `2014/02/14 11:35:00`, I get the expected results:

```
2014/5/5 02:43:59
2014/5/6 02:22:09
2014/5/7 02:00:19
2014/5/8 01:38:29
2014/5/9 01:16:39
2014/5/9 01:16:49
2014/5/10 00:54:49
2014/5/10 00:54:59
2014/5/11 00:33:09
2014/5/12 00:11:19
2014/5/12 23:49:29
```

Since The first example is giving satisfactory results, I would not say that my model caused the difference but it could. So my question is, what do I do wrong with this epoch time?

Comment: What is the value `Ona`? In the case where you raise the inclination to 49°, your second `if` statement is firing on more than two hundred more occasions than when the inclination is lower. What is ONA and why are you throwing out moments when the ONA is greater than 5 or less than -5?

Comment: `Ona` is the off nadir angle, it is computed from the elevation following the formulas found in [_Geospatial technology for earth observation_, p81](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/72/bok%253A978-1-4419-0050-0.pdf?auth66=1398332293_44c332cf27721e9b1550cba21029e7e3&ext=.pdf). The moments thrown out are the moments when the ground station is not in the cone of view of the satellite, defined by its off nadir angle, here 5 deg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the epoch time in both STK and my model to the beginning of the experiment, here `2014/04/26 16:00:00`, I don't have the shift in the results anymore.

I do understand that the error on the satellite position grows proportionally with the difference between the epoch of the mean anomaly and the time of analysis, but I don't understand why this error leads to a shift in the results and not in completely different results.

Note that the conversion between elevation and off nadir angle here is quite good, provided that the value `h + R`, distance between the satellite and the Earth center (`range + Earth_radius`), is corrected by the altitude on Earth, that is `h + R + target_altitude`.

I mark my question as solved, since I obtained the desired results, but an explanation on the shift effect is welcomed!

I take this opportunity to thank Brandon Rhodes for the great work on PyEphem.